# Combining Functions

Tags: php, function, codeigniter

How can put return tow function following in one function `marge()` and echo it with `json_encode`.

```
 function get_gr()
{
            //$tourf_id = $this->input->post('toname');
            $id = '102';

            $query = $this->db->order_by('id','desc')->get_where('table1', array('id' => $id));
            if ($query->num_rows() == 0) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                $query = $query->row();
                return array('guide' => $query->guide);
            }
}

function get_res()
{
            //$id   = $this->input->post('name');
            $id = '102';
            $data = array();
            $query_r = $this->db->order_by('id','desc')->get_where('table2', array('relation' => $id));
            if($query_r->num_rows() > 0){
                foreach ($query_r->result() as $row) {
                    $data[] = array(
                                            'name_re' => $row->name_re,
                                            'id' => $row->id
                                        );
                }
                return $hotel_data;
            }else{
                return 0;
            }
}
function marge(){
    echo json_encode(get_gr().get_res()); //This line 991
}
```

I get this erroe from above php code:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_gr() in D:\xampp\htdocsapplication\controllers\faile.php on line 991
```

What do i do?

Comment: Given that is line 991, are you sure that all the functions are being included properly?

Comment: I want merging result(array) tow function in on function, your code have same above error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If inside a controller, you must refer to `get_gr()` as `$this->get_gr()`

Answer (score 0):

You can do a merge as two array elements.

```
echo json_encode(array(get_gr(), get_res()));
```

Comment: I want merging result(array) tow function in on function, your code have same above error.

Comment: Ok, but you are merging two elements as string, however, your functions return array or integer